# How can I resolve the value of a textblock inside a grid?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-8, grid, windows-phone

I have a `ListbBox` that contains grid items. Inside grids are `TextBlocks`. How can I resolve the textblock.Text of each listbox item?

I think that  `listbox.Items[index-1]` returns an `object` but I can't get the textblock value.

I create  dynamically

```
    Grid g = new Grid();
    g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
```

And then

```
    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
    txt.Text = "some dynamically text";
```

And

```
    g.Children.Add(txt);

    listbox.Items.Add(g);
```

where `listbox` is my `ListBox`

When I load some values I want to resolve the text

```
    int epilogi = listbox.SelectedIndex;
    listbox.Items.RemoveAt(epilogi);
    object tempkati =  listbox.Items[epilogi-1];
```

I want the text from the tempkati object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
var grid = listbox.Items[epilogi - 1] as Grid;
var textblock = grid.Children[0] as TextBlock;
var text = textblock.Text;
```